# Objective C Address Book Check if User Exists by ID

Tags: objective-c, addressbook

I am having trouble checking to see if a user exists in the address book in objective C. I have the unique ID of the user as i save that in a DB.

```
if(ABRecordGetRecordID((__bridge ABRecordRef)([contacts objectAtIndex:i])) != NULL)
```

I am running that in a while look picking up the unique ID saved in a array called contacts.